# Difference between "pajama", "pyjama" and "paijama"

Tags: word-choice, differences

Which is the correct word: *pajama*, *pyjama* or *paijama*?

Is there a difference between these three?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Pajama* is the American spelling while *pyjama* is the British spelling. Both mean the same.

> **Pajama/Pyjama:**  loose-fitting clothes worn for sleep

*Paijama* is the word from which *pajama/pyjama* has been derived. Also, the meaning (of *pajama/pyjama*) has been altered a bit.

> **Paijama:** loose, lightweight trousers fitted with drawstring waistbands

*Pajama/Pyjama* was incorporated into the English language during the British Rule in India.

(*Bonus:* Most people in India call it either "paijama" or "pajama")